# ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled() not working on KitKat

Tags: android, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

`ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled()` is not working on KitKat. It does work fine on Lollipop.

What maybe the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: What type is the view, that you are trying to apply nested scrolling?

Comment: *not working* ... *What maybe the issue* => Well, since you only said it's not working, carefully omitting *any* detail on the error, how would anyone know ? Now's a good time to read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: Android L and M device, working nested scroll view ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled()

Comment: but below Android L device it is not scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lots of search and found my self solution !!!
I am happy for this code and working fine

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```